# @Autowired and @Service working from controller but not from a different package

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-3, autowired

I need help understanding the concept behind `@Autowired` and `@Service`. I have a DAO defined with `@Service` and controller with `@Autowired` and everything seems fine, however, I use the same `@Autowired` in a different class then it does not work.

Example:

Service

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource (DataSource myDataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(myDataSource);
    } 

    public void testUpdate(){
            jdbcTemplate.update("some query");
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.springtest.mywork.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.html")
public class MyController
{
  @Autowired
  MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String test(Model model)
  {
    systemsService.testUpdate();
    return "view/test";
  }
}
```

The above all works fine. However, If I want to use `MyService` in a POJO then it just doesn't work. Example:

```
package com.springtest.mywork.pojos;
public class MyPojo {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    public void testFromPojo () {
        myService.someDataAccessMethod(); //myService is still null
    }
}
```

Spring Config:

```
<beans>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest.mywork" />
    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="hello" />
        <property name="password" value="what" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Comment: Is `MyPojo` instantiated by Spring?

Comment: I have not done anything for `MyController` in config.xml so i didn't do it for `MyPojo` either. What should I be doing?

Comment: Can you post your Spring config?

Comment: updated with spring config added at the bottom

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because your POJO class is not managed by spring container.

`@Autowire` annotation will work only those objects which are managed by spring (ie created by the spring container).

In your case the service and controller object are managed by spring, but your POJO class is not managed by spring, that is why the `@Autowire` is not producing the behavior expected by you.

Another problem I noticed is, you are using the `@Service` annotation in the DAO layer when spring has the `@Repository` annotation specifically created for this purpose.

Also it is not desirable to allow spring to manage the POJO classes since normally it will be data storage elements which has to be created outside the container.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17940/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-birdy)

Answer (score 5):

When using classpath scanning, you have to communicate to Spring which classes to manage.  This is done using the `@Service` annotation, and its relations (`@Controller`, `@Repository`, etc).

If you choose *not* to annotate your bean, you must explicitly declare it in your config, just like you did with `dataSource` and `jdbcTemplate`.

Annotating your classes means only those classes in the package are managed by Spring; which allows you to scan a package without having to manage *all* classes in that package.

Comment: So I should annotate my POJO with `@Service` or `@Repository` or `@Controller`?

Comment: I would prefer to add annotation rather than define it in the xml

Comment: "Annotating your classes prevents every class in a package being managed by Spring; something that isn't often desirable." really? so in a package only one class can be annotated?

Comment: `@Service` is the most non-specific, so that's what I'd use.

Comment: @birdy I mean, by annotating, you choose which classes to be managed.

Comment: even with @Service it is coming to NULL :(

Comment: And it's in the same package?

Comment: no. Its in a different package. Controller is in `com.springtest.mywork.controller` and pojo is in `com.springtest.mywork.mypojo` . In the spring config I have `<context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest.mywork" />` so I'm assuming both sub packages `controller` and `mypojo` should be scanned...?

Comment: Try adding `<context:annotation-config>` (as @Pradeep mentions below)

Comment: still same. I give up. perhaps i need to step away

Answer (score 2):

Include this in applicationContext.xml file

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this to use spring-managed beans in your POJO class.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/using-spring-managed-bean-in-non-managed-object.html

Comment: Please avoid link only answers.

Answer (score -1):

check your context component scan in your configuration file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<your_package>" />
```

Comment: I've checked this. It is scanning all the packages.